# Uncaught Error: Using only allowed for the collection of a single element

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I saw  Uncaught Error in console please help me

```
 bootstrap-datepicker.js:1679 Uncaught Error: Using only allowed for the collection of a single element (getFormattedDate function)
        at w.fn.init.datepickerPlugin [as datepicker] (bootstrap-datepicker.js:1679)
        at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (common.js:369)
        at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
        at Datepicker._trigger (bootstrap-datepicker.js:460)
```

Comment: This is too less information. Please write your html and css code where you use the datepicker function

Answer (score 1):

I encountered myself with the same error

It happens because your jquery selector is not unique and contains multiple datepickers elements, as such the plugin does not understand how to return the date

Make sure you only get one element in your selector

```javascript
$('.datepicker').get(0).datepicker('getDate')
```

Or use a foreach

```javascript
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
    var date = this.datepicker('getDate'); //Do something with the date
}
```